# PHP get variable of parent class

Tags: php

I'm trying OO in PHP. I think I understand what goes wrong but I don't understand how to fix it.

```
class Name {
   public $_firstname;
   public $_lastname;

   public function setName($firstName, $lastName){
       $this->_firstname = $firstName;
       $this->_lastname = $lastName;                
   }

   public function getName(){
       echo 'The full name is '. $this->_firstname. ' ' . $this->_lastname .'<br>';
   }

}
class Description extends Name{
    public $_desciprion;

    public function setDescription($description){
        $this->_desciprion = $description;
    }
    public function getDescription(){
        echo $this->_desciprion. ' is written by '.$this->_firstname .'<br>';
    }
}

$firstNames = array("some", "another", "john");
$lastNames = array("body", "body", "doe");
$descriptions = array("description 1", "description 2", "description 3");



for ($i=0; $i < count($firstNames); $i++){
    $name = new Name();
    $name->setName($firstNames[$i], $lastNames[$i]);

    $description = new Description();
    $description->setDescription($descriptions[$i]);

    echo $description->getDescription();
}
```

I want to echo the `$description` containing the `$_firstname` of the `Name` class.

I don't really know the OO way to fill it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Honestly - I don't think `Description` should be a sub-type of `Name` anyway; it's a different *"thing"*.

Comment: @CD001 I'm learning this so it doesn't really matter if it's logic as long as the syntax is correct!

Comment: Fair enough - but if you're learning you may as well know *when* to sub-type a class - a sub-type should be a more specialized version of a type; `Pug` could be a sub-type of `Dog` which could be a sub-type of `Mammal` which could be a sub-type of `Vertebrate` ... and so on. That way `new Pug()` inherits the properties of `Dog`, `Mammal` and `Vertebrate`.

Comment: @CD001That's absolutely true.... Thnx tho' I now understand that to get the value I have to name the object I'm working in and execute the function of a parent

Comment: OOP is all about interfaces. What is the interface that your two classes share? Answer is that the baseclass implicitly defines the common interface. Now, think about what you can do with a `Description` instance if you only use the common interface? Answer is, that they are both completely indistinguishable, which is another indicator that you picked a bad example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `$name` is completely unrelated to `$description`. However, this is easily fixed:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($firstNames); $i++){
    $description = new Description();
    $description->setName($firstNames[$i], $lastNames[$i]);
    $description->setDescription($descriptions[$i]);

    echo $description->getDescription();
}
```

Bonus improvement:

```
foreach ($firstNames as $i => $firstName){
    $description = new Description();
    $description->setName($firstName, $lastNames[$i]);
    $description->setDescription($descriptions[$i]);

    echo $description->getDescription();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I now see that `$description` can use the function of `Name`. However can you explain why your second option is an improvement?

Comment: I'd also move the `$description = new Description()` and put it before the loop begins. makes things faster. If OP has lots of logic in the `__construct()` function for example, it could make things slower

Comment: I understood that it would be faster and saver to build a new object for every instance.

Comment: @Interactive, this is highly subjective, but I think most folks consider foreach loops to be a bit more readable than for loops.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($firstNames); $i++){
    $description = new Description();
    $description->setName($firstNames[$i], $lastNames[$i]);
    $description->setDescription($descriptions[$i]);

    echo $description->getDescription();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the name to another instance ( $name ) in order to set the name to the description object you have to write:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($firstNames); $i++){

    $description = new Description();
    $description->setName($firstNames[$i], $lastNames[$i]);
    $description->setDescription($descriptions[$i]);

    echo $description->getDescription();
}
```